On bounds for the factors of integers
Let $N=p q$ and for a real constant $D>1$ assume $\log{q} \approx D \log{p}$.
Conjecture 1 There exist positive real constant $A$ depending
only on $D$ such that given integer $r$ in the range
$[q-q^{\frac{D-1}{D}},q+q^{\frac{D-1}{D}}]$
with probability $A$ we have $p=\lfloor \frac{N}{r}\rfloor$.
As a corollary given $N,r$ we factor $N$ in $O(1)$ using only
one division of integers.
Conjecture 2 The interval $[q-q^{\frac{D-1}{D}},q+q^{\frac{D-1}{D}}]$
contains bounded by $B$ rational number of the forms $\frac{N}{a}$
for integers $a$ and we can enumerate them all in time $O(B)$,
finding the factor $q=\frac{N}{p}$.

Q3 Can we find similar intervals $[f_1(p),f_2(p)]$ for the
smaller prime $p$?

Closely related is the short note Efficient probabilistic algorithm for integer factorization given bounds for one factor
Experimental data:
sage: %runfile sin3.sage
sage: brutemain1(B=2**100,lim=100,seed=1)
log_2(p)=100 D=2 all=100 good=44 good%=44
log_2(p)=100 D=3 all=100 good=42 good%=42
log_2(p)=100 D=3/2 all=100 good=46 good%=46
log_2(p)=100 D=5/2 all=100 good=47 good%=47


Merry Christmas to those who celebrate it
